# Indicator in Picasa database that a Face Suggestion was removed

Tags: picasa

I've adapted Skisoo's PicasaDBReader (https://skisoo.com/blog/en/2013/how-to-read-picasa-3-9-database-and-extract-faces/) to pull the Picasa metadata into a SQL Server database. One of the things I want to see is what photos in an album have unidentified faces, so that I can identify them and save the face tag to the file.

Picasa suggests a lot of faces and many of them I dismiss by clicking the X on the suggestion. Picasa remembers which ones I dismissed. However the imagedata files don't seem to have any marker for which face suggestions are dismissed - they appear the same as non-dismissed suggestions, with personAlbumId=0 and one or two personAlbumRecs.

Does anyone know where Picasa stores the flag that it is dismissed? Currently not much use in checking if I can't eliminate faces I don't want to save.